# Printing Through ESC POS Printer via usb for windows app in flutter

Tags: windows, flutter, thermal-printer, escpos, flutter-windows

I'm new to flutter, right no I'm trying to develop an app for windows that can print a ticket via USB from a thermal printer. I have been trying to communicate with the printer using a few plugins, I have tried `pos_printer_manager`, and `flutter_pos_printer_platform` (discontinued), but have not succeeded.

Can you guys tell me how to send data via USB to the thermal printer in Windows, or maybe anyone can recommend on a good package with complete documentation?

Answer (score 0):

Use this -  `usb_esc_printer_windows:`

```
List<int> bytes = [];

// Sending esc commands to printer
final sendToPrint =
          await usb_esc_printer_windows.sendPrintRequest(bytes, 'POS-80C');
```